# Angular unit tests are failing only on build server

Tags: karma-runner, circleci, docker-container, angular-test

All pull requests circleci pipelines fail while running unit tests.

Unit tests are successful on local development machine but failing while on build server in Docker Container.

Error is

```
17 12 2020 10:55:35.283:ERROR [karma-server]: UnhandledRejection: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
17 12 2020 10:55:35.284:ERROR [karma-server]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
```

I tried the solution proposed in this post, but still not working
https://ievgen.de/2020/11/17/angular-tests-fail-docker/

Any ideas ?

---

CircleCi executor config:

```
executors:
  node-lts:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:14-browsers
    working_directory: ~/ng
```

---

Karma.config:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/pricetracer'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessCI: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox'],
      },
    },
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```

Comment: Are your unittests running async?

Answer (score 0):

"UnhandledRejection" because Karma Runner is not compatible with Node Version 15. You have to downgrade your node version below or equal to 14.

Karma Runner Open Issue - https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/3571